# How to fetch the string from the column of table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table

```
Userid  District_code
1        05
1        03
2        03
2        04
3        06
```

and want to get this output:

```
userid=1 dist_code(05,03)
```

Comment: It looks like you're wanting to do string aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 'userid=' || Userid::text
     , 'dist_code(' || string_agg(District_code::text, ',') || ')'
FROM table
GROUP BY Userid
-- WHERE userid=1
```